# I am precious to you, but kill me you do. ... What is my name?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> I am precious to you,
>   but kill me you do.
>
> I am older than you,
>   but still ever new.
>
> I cannot be sold,
>   for money or gold.
>
> I can EVEN fly.
>   Yet wings have not I.
>
> This is no game,
>   what is my name?

Give the name and  a brief reasoning.

Comment: Your name is G. Rassovsky. :^)

Comment: @Mazura I flagged a moderator to edit my comment but nothing happened so I've deleted my comment. Here it is again in non-spoiler format: "(+10) I guessed the answer just from the title. I think this type of riddle is overused."

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are:

> Time

**Explanation**
I am precious to you,

> Time is precious

but kill me you do.

> One kills time.

I am older than you,

> Time has always been

but still ever new.

> What has not been seen is fresh

I cannot be sold, for money or gold.

> Money does not buy time

I can EVEN fly. Yet wings have not I.

> "Time flies". AND it progresses in an "EVEN"/steady/constant manner - i.e. "at an even pace".

This is no game,
what is my name?

> Poetic style :)

Comment: No cheating intended :D

Comment: Oh goodness. I was too slow... well I think mine was up first (I know you didn't cheat) :p but I had no explanation

Comment: This comment was actually up first (like 10 seconds) :D

Comment: @AndreaGottardi but yours had explanation... one can tell I was trained in StackOverflow  :p

Comment: Yes, that was the answer and interpretation I was looking for (namely that ppl kill time).
However no one has mentioned the wordplay at 'EVEN fly' :P

Comment: @G.Rassovsky Evening?

Comment: nah, rather 'evenly' - at a constant speed...

Comment: @G.Rassovsky Ah, good one... how about "I even constantly fly" or "I even fly regularly"?

Comment: @d'alar'cop well the idea is more of constant flight rather than regular flight... you can add it to the answer so that it is complete :)

Comment: I'd like to argue against this tradtional answer: Every working person sells their time for money, and that equation is as old as work itself.  So you cannot *buy* time with money, but you can definitely sell your own.

Comment: @Zibbobz Ah, you are right... put that on the main question

Comment: Not a fan of the 'even' wordplay in the OP, since time *does* move at different rates.

Comment: @Geobits Ah indeed, with relativity and all that... hard to argue here, but I'd offer that in a classical riddle one must consider both simple human experience and the intricacies of science. I mean a classic riddle wouldn't normally really require special knowledge about something like relativity :p (although it may). So, I think it's about coinciding valid-enough interpretations reading to a single solution

Comment: @Zibbobz, +1, also I'd like to argue that you can buy time. I believe that this is the main motivation behind employing workers or hiring contractors - you free up your time to do whatever it is you feel is more important.

Answer (score 29):

Something different!

> Bacteria in/on your body

I am precious to you, but kill me you do.

> We wouldn't be able to survive long without it however our body is constantly killing off bacteria

I am older than you, but still ever new.

> It's been around longer than humans but what is with us is constantly rejuvenating.

I cannot be sold, for money or gold.

> Not so typical to sell your bacteria (unlike our time how many people get paid per the hour...)

I can EVEN fly. Yet wings have not I.

> We sneeze, its airborne...

Comment: Love the creativity.  My wife has bought (the product you mentioned) for making certain cheeses, but you make a good point that it's similar to buying someone's time.

Comment: You can sell bacteria, just not on eBay... ;-)

Comment: +1 from me for creativity. You maxed out your rep on your first day. Not too shabby. ;)

Answer (score 15):

> You are... The Precious! [image] ([*Lord of the Rings*, imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120737/))

I am precious to you,
but kill me you do.

> "It is precious to me, though I buy it with a great pain."

I am older than you,
but still ever new.

> An ancient artifact, harmed only by the fires that forged it.

I cannot be sold,
for money or gold.

> No ring bearer would ever part with the Precious for something so paltry as money.

I can EVEN fly.
Yet wings have not I.

> "The Ring of Power has a will of its own. It betrayed Isildur, to his death." Getting *even* and 'flying' from its bearer.

This is no game,
what is my name?

> "**DO NOT TAKE ME FOR SOME CONJURER OF CHEAP TRICKS**."

Answer (score 10):

> Time

***I am precious to you,
but kill me you do.***

> Time is money

***I am older than you,
but still ever new.***

> There is always a quantity of time bigger than your age

***I cannot be sold,
for money or gold.***

> You cannot buy time

***I can EVEN fly.
Yet wings have not I.***

> Sometimes you say "time flies"

Answer (score 8):

You are...

> Air

I am precious to you, but kill me you do.

> We need air to survive, but constantly consume it in our metabolisms. We also spoil it by polluting.

I am older than you, but still ever new.

> Air has been around for ages, but is constantly "renewed" by photosynthesis which converts carbon dioxide in it to oxygen which can be breathed again.

I cannot be sold, for money or gold.

> While bottled air is a thing in certain dystopic scenarios, breathing air is commonly accepted as a universal right that shouldn't need to be bought.

I can EVEN fly. Yet wings have not I.

> Air flies, in its way, despite having no wings.

Comment: Along the same lines, I was thinking specifically oxygen.

Answer (score 4):

> Time. 
>  Time is precious, and yet sometimes we "kill" it, as in waste it. 
> He's "older" than anyone, since it existed before anyone, and yet there's always more time, so "when" we're living is, technically, new time. 
> Can't be sold, well, I dont know what more I can say about this :) 
>  Time flies, usually when you're having fun, despite not having wings

edit: Ninja'd :(

Comment: sorry Ciacciu :(

Comment: Np :D
I just noticed i was double-ninja'd :)

Answer (score 2):

> The environment

***I am precious to you,
but kill me you do.***

> Everybody needs the environment but are destroying it.

***I am older than you,
but still ever new.***

> The environment was there long before anybody, but new plants, animals are being born every day.

***I cannot be sold,
for money or gold.***

> You cannot buy the environment.

***I can EVEN fly.
Yet wings have not I.***

> The environment can "fly" from place-to-place.

Comment: what do you mean by the environment being able "fly" from place-to-place? This part didn't click at all for me. Do you mean the entire planet? because that would really affect the entire answer.

Comment: @yoniLavi Fungal Spores can fly and they don't have wings and they are part of the enviroment.